# Can't Trigger EventBus from Inside Http Request (RxJava, Kotlin, Android)

Tags: java, android, kotlin, rx-java, event-bus

I have an eventbus that's "working" within an `onResume` function in my `mainActivity`. I can push events through my EventBus, but **only** when those events don't come from inside an http request. Of course, my use case is to get the results of an http request, push them to an event bus, and have that event bus send the result to a fragment. So this is an issue.

Here is my `mainActivity` so far:

```
class MainActivity: AppCompatActivity(){

    var mainMessage: Disposable?=null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
        getSupportActionBar()?.hide();

        view_pager.adapter = TabsAdapter(supportFragmentManager)
        tab_layout.setupWithViewPager(view_pager)
    }

    public override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        mainMessage = MainEventBus.INSTANCE.toObserverable().subscribe({
            println("MESSAGE SENT FROM MAINACTIVITY")
            println(it)
        })
    }

    public override fun onStop() {
        mainMessage?.dispose()
        super.onStop()
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        val testEvent = MainEventBus.Companion.KeyValue(key = "testkey", value = "keyvalue")
        MainEventBus.INSTANCE.send(testEvent)
        weatherRequests()
    }

    private fun weatherRequests(){
        "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Austin,us&appid=abd532567a4d169ee04f6597584ba084".httpGet().responseJson { _, _, result ->
            //do something with response
            result.fold(success = { json ->
                println("success from json request to weatherAPI")
                val weatherArray = result.get().obj().getJSONArray("weather").get(0) as JSONObject
                println("value of main in weatherArray:" + weatherArray["main"])
                println("value of description in weatherArray:" + weatherArray["description"])
                println("value of icon in weatherArray: " + weatherArray["icon"])
                val mainWeatherEvent = MainEventBus.Companion.KeyValue(key="mainWeather", value = weatherArray["main"].toString())
                val descriptionWeatherEvent = MainEventBus.Companion.KeyValue(key="descriptionWeather", value = weatherArray["description"].toString())
                val weatherurl = "http://openweathermap.org/img/w/"+weatherArray["icon"].toString()+".png"
                val iconWeatherEvent = MainEventBus.Companion.KeyValue(key="iconWeather", value = weatherurl)

                println("BEFORE SENDING EVENTBUS ITEMS")
                MainEventBus.INSTANCE.send(mainWeatherEvent)
                MainEventBus.INSTANCE.send(descriptionWeatherEvent)
                MainEventBus.INSTANCE.send(iconWeatherEvent)
                println("AFTER SENDING EVENTBUS ITEMS")

            }, failure = { error ->
                Log.e("qdp error", error.toString())
            })
        }

        Log.d("aftertag","after fuel Request")
    }

}
```

So my output sees this:

```
I/System.out: INSIDE EVENTBUS
I/System.out: VALUE OF KEYVALUE
I/System.out: KeyValue(key=testkey, value=keyvalue)
I/System.out: MESSAGE SENT FROM MAINACTIVITY
I/System.out: KeyValue(key=testkey, value=keyvalue)
```

Which is the test event that is fired directly from my `onResume` function. But I get no trigger notifications from the http request event bus calls from within my `weatherRequests` function. Why aren't these firing?

My event bus is very simple, and I don't think it's the problem. (I think there's an issue with my lifecycle somehow in `mainActivity`). But I'll include it just for completeness:

```
enum class MainEventBus {

    INSTANCE;

    companion object {
        data class KeyValue(var key: String, var value: String)
    }

    private val bus = PublishSubject.create<KeyValue>() // the actual publisher handling all of the events

    fun send(keyValue: KeyValue) {
        println("INSIDE EVENTBUS")
        println("VALUE OF KEYVALUE")
        println(keyValue)
        bus.onNext(keyValue)
//        bus.onNext({key, message}) // the message being sent to all subscribers
    }

    fun toObserverable(): Observable<KeyValue> {
        return bus // return the publisher itself as an observable to subscribe to
    }

}
```

Comment: The potential issue, apart from using an event bus, could be that you are calling `send`, aka `onNext`, from multiple threads which is not allowed. See if `bus = PublishSubject.create<KeyValue>().toSerialized()` solves this problem or not.

Comment: So if event bus can't be used across multiple threads, and http requests must run in a background thread in order to be async, then does that mean that event buses are not able to be used from an http request? That's kind of useless....Also, the serialized idea doesn't break it, but I still get the same error.

Comment: How do you observe the event bus? Maybe your `onPause` disposes the `Observer` but doesn't subscribe a fresh one in `onResume`.

Comment: My `mainActivity` page is shown above - everything that I do to make an observer is in there. I could try remaking it `onResume`, but then why does my `testEvent` fire? I don't think that's the solution.

Comment: Put a `println` into `onStop` and see if it appears before events stop. Also use `println(bus.hasObservers())` in send to see if there is actually an observer for the bus or not.

Comment: So `println(bus.hasObservers())` prints `true`.    `public override fun onStop() {
        println("THIS IS THE ONSTOP METHOD")
        mainMessage?.dispose()
        super.onStop()
    }` never prints the `println` - probably because my `mainActivity` never stops (it's a simple 3 tab tablayout).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165587/discussion-between-peter-weyand-and-akarnokd).